# Python - pyinstaller script not working when executing the .exe

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pyinstaller

I am trying to make a executable of a python script, this script is for use with the google drive api, i have copy and paste the token.pickle file, and the client_secret.json file inside the folder where the .exe is but i have this traceback when i execute the script

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Myscript.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 68, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "googleapiclient\http.py", line 67, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 531, in exec_module
  File "googleapiclient\model.py", line 36, in <module>
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 465, in get_distribution
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 341, in get_provider
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 884, in require
  File "pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 770, in resolve
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'google-api-python-client' distribution was not found and is required by the application
[13660] Failed to execute script Myscript
```

it seems like some modules are not found in the executable , the comand i used to convert the .py file into .exe was

```
pyinstaller -c -F myscript.py
```

how can i ensure that the required modules are included in the exe file

Comment: so every file except the python file are in the folder where the executable is ?

Comment: yes , because the script needs to find those files

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) to the package

Comment: could you please explain me how i do it, the exe need to be used by my coworkers in their pc, also why i need it if the script works fine without converting to exe